# How to update table value in wordpress with update query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is the code, I am updating col name `custom_status` of `wp_users` table for post data user email. Insert works fine, but the update query is not working.

Code Here:

```
if (isset($_POST["email_type"]) == 'News' ) {
    $wpdb->update('wp_users', array('custom_status' => 'News'), WHERE, array('user_email' => $_POST["user_email"] ));
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The documentation for ```update``` says that a third ```where``` parameter is required.

Comment: nop, no any error till now. hope query is right.  plz can you check.

Comment: I cannot check anymore than I already have, without knowing what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to set ```custom_status``` for all users? Or for a single user? Look into the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) for ```update```, specifically the ```where``` parameter.

Comment: Sorry editing the question.

Comment: I have edit the question.  update the specific col by post data of email id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add third argument which row you will update for example:

```
if (isset($_POST["email_type"]) == 'News' ) {
    $wpdb->update('wp_users', array('custom_status' => 'News'), array( 'ID' => 1 ));
}
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Its working. col custom_status has been updated with value News